# Wordpress: Use dynamic column name in update statement

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm struggling with a generic update/insert statement where I want to use a variable that hold the column name that needs to be updated/inserted.

My code looks like this:

```
if ($count > 0) {
    $wpdb->update($dbTable, array('Agility' => $allResults), array('Date' => 
    $today, 'UserID' => $userID));

}else{
    $wpdb->insert($dbTable, array('UserID' => $userID, 'Date' => $today, 
    'Agility' => $allResults));

}
```

I've tried to change the 'Agility' to $columnName but it doesn't seem to work.

Please help

Thanks.
Flemming

Comment: Generally, that will work. How exactly did your code look, and are you sure that `$columnName` contained the correct name of the column?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post more info to be able to get help. What exactly do you mean by 'doesn't seem to work' ? Does it give you an error or just not do anything? What's your underlying table structure?

You may need to use the `format` parameter for update and insert (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) to make sure your UserID and Date are being properly compared according to their type. The way you're using column names should work though.